# java.net.SocketTimeoutException (ANDROID)

Tags: java, android, socket-timeout-exception

I have used following code to connect -

```
URL url = new URL("https://results.bput.ac.in/");

HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 20);

urlc.connect();
```

It returned a **SocketTimeoutException** .

***Exception***

The exact exception i am getting is

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to results.bput.ac.in/14.139.212.166 (port 443) after 90000ms
```

*and sometimes this -*

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to results.bput.ac.in/14.139.212.166 (port 80) after 90000ms
```

- tried with removing the `urlc.setConnectTimeout(1000 * 20);` and still got the exception.
- checked with *http instead of https* `URL url = new URL("http://results.bput.ac.in/");` but got no result.
- cheked with `URL url = new URL("https://www.facebook.com/");` and got success response.
- Checked with changing the timeout period but same exception .

The problem is with this specific url - `http://results.bput.ac.in/` .

***Information***

This link i have given `http://results.bput.ac.in/` is perfectly working on any web browser without any lagging .

I got information that some guys cant open this site , its lagging but i can open it without any lag .

***My Research***

I have already tried [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608499/getting-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out-in-android) , [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046707/android-java-net-sockettimeoutexception-connection-timed-out) , [this github solution](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/146) and [java code geeks solution](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/net/sockettimeoutexception/java-net-sockettimeoutexception-how-to-solve-sockettimeoutexception/) but got no result.

***Update***

I have tested this with my wifi and mobile data by thinking that my router might have some problem with the port. but i got same exception with mobile data too.

Do anyone have any solution to this.

Comment: is that link working ?

Comment: i have edited my question. @PankajNimgade the link works.

Comment: i tried that link in browser, but it times out, are you sure

Comment: i tried it now @PankajNimgade and this took like 1 sec to load .

Answer (score 2):

> If the `hostname` resolves to multiple IP addresses, this client will try each in [RFC 3484](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt) order. If connecting to each of these addresses fails, multiple timeouts will elapse before the connect attempt throws an exception. Host names that support both `IPv6` and `IPv4` always have at least 2 IP addresses.--
>   [Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html)

You have already used `setConnectTimeout()` and added maximum time as well so no doubt on that.  The main reason of **SocketTimeoutException** is if the timeout elapses before a connection is established.

Then the main and certain reason is **Connection with your server could not be established.**

Comment: what would i do then ? any solution ?

Comment: Be sure that you can open that `URL` and establish proper connection. your server is not responding but `https://www.facebook.com` will do, so that it's working fine. This means you have nothing to do with this error in client side untill you fix the connection timeout problem.

Comment: i have also tried not giving any timeout period and thats giving error too .

Comment: No, that won't work, don't remove that. Just be sure you can open that URL from your device's browser in short duration of time.

Comment: If you can smoothly open that from your browser then your code should work fine. But i think it's still lagging. It's not being opened by us.

Comment: so if you cant open this link i have given then whats the way to tackle this problem ? because i can open it and you cant but you are saying it is lagging. so should i just increase the timeout period.

Comment: Yah you can try increasing that as well, How much time does it take to open this from your browser ?

Comment: instantly opens , and it worst case it open in 1 sec .

Comment: `SocketTimeoutException` means *either* a connect timeout *or* a read timeout. *In this case* it means a connect timeout.

Comment: @EJP I am also saying so, *if the timeout elapses before a connection is established.* Then why it's eligible for down?

Answer (score 0):

I tried both https://results.bput.ac.in/ and http://results.bput.ac.in/ and both timed out. Probably you haven't opened ports 80 and/or 443 in the server firewall.

Comment: how do i do that ?